# How to adding space in middle of alphanumeric string?

Tags: php, string

I have a string like `cs123` and I want to add space in the middle alphanumeric values in PHP. Is there any function for doing this specifically in PHP?

I have **`cs123`** and I want **`cs 123`**.

Comment: You can take a shot at regex matching with [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) or even work something out by looping [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php). Anyways, your question is way off topic because you have shown no effort. Try those functions and if you get stuck then try asking again and add your code example.

Comment: Is it always chars then numbers? Or can it be char-num-char or any other sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace("/([a-z]+)([0-9]+)/i", "$1 $2", "cs123"); // Outputs: cs 123
```

in case "123cs" => "123 cs"

```
echo preg_replace("/([0-9]+)([a-z]+)/i", "$1 $2", "123cs"); // Outputs: 123 cs
```

we can combine both:

```
$text = "cs123, 123cs";
$new_text = preg_replace("/([a-z]+)([0-9]+)/i", "$1 $2", $text);
$new_text = preg_replace("/([0-9]+)([a-z]+)/i", "$1 $2", $new_text);
// $new_text = "cs 123, 123 cs"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> $array = preg_split('#(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)#i', "cs123")

it will check every character in given string and split it at position where 'before' element is a letter

> (?<=[a-z])

and 'after' element is a digit

> (?=\d)

then you can just implode this array with a ' ' as a $glue parameter.